# How can I get close places using GMSPlacesClient with specific keyword or type?

Tags: ios, google-places-api, google-places

Using Google Maps SDK for iOS, I would like to retrieve closest places filtering them using type and keyword, but I don't see how.
How can I do that?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client

Comment: I've been wanting to do this also. I don't think 'tis possible with their mobile SDK. I do know that it works via web

Comment: I'm using a wrapper of the web service and it's working. See https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTGooglePlacesAPI Although I would prefer to use the iOS SDK.

Comment: I've just created mine using NSMutableURLRequest with the result thrown as JSON. I do hope they can ammend this to their api.

Comment: Can you share it using a gist or similar? Thanks.

Comment: It's quite easy to do, just refer to this guide: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search